# How can I redirect the page when I click on an suggestive item from React Semantic UI Search Module?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, search, create-react-app, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to create a search bar built on the top of Semantic UI React like this:
[image]
resource: [standard search](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search/#types-standard)

I am currently using `create-react-app` with `Link` and `Switch` from `react-router-dom`. I have already tried similar solutions with `history.push`, but didn't redirect the page with my list. I could not found any example on how to redirect the page after I click on an item and outputs a div with a list in the new page containing some objects from Search result.

Here are some templates of my files structure:

###App.js###

```js
export default function App() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ProductList} />
                <Route path ="/details" component={Details} />
                <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
                <Route path="/form" component={Form} />
                <Route component={Default} />
            </Switch>
            ...
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

I need to redirect to `/details` page after I click on the suggestive item.

###SearchForItem.js###

```js
class SearchForItem extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.resetComponent()
    }

    goToDetailsPageDiv(e, result) {
        {console.log(result)}
        return (
            <Link to="/details">
                <ui>
                    <li>{result.title}</li>
                    <li>{result.description}</li>
                    <li>{result.image}</li>
                </ui>
            </Link>
        );
    }

    resetComponent = () => this.setState({ isLoading: false, results: [], value: '' })

    handleResultSelect = (e, { result }) => this.goToDetailsPageDiv(e, result);

    handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true, value })

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.state.value.length < 1) return this.resetComponent()

            const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(this.state.value), 'i')
            const isMatch = result => re.test(result.title)
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                results: _.filter(source, isMatch),
            })
        }, 300)
    }


    render() {
        const { isLoading, value, results } = this.state
        return (
            <Search
                onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
                onSearchChange={_.debounce(this.handleSearchChange, 500, { leading: true })}
                loading={isLoading}
                results={results}
                value={value}
                //
                input={{placeholder: "Search..."}}
                noResultsMessage={"Nothing found"}
                {...this.props}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

`onResultSelect` is supposed to handle the data after I click on these items.

The `console.log` outputs correctly all the object's properties after I clicked on the target item:

```
{
  description: "description-template"
  image: "img/products/product-template"
  title: "title-template"
}
```

But the issue I am trying to solve is to redirect these properties to the page `/details` inside a div with a list with these 3 properties similar to what I tried to produce here:

```
goToDetailsPageDiv(e, result) {
        {console.log(result)}
        return (
            <Link to="/details">
                <ui>
                    <li>{result.title}</li>
                    <li>{result.description}</li>
                    <li>{result.image}</li>
                </ui>
            </Link>
        );
    }
```

Can someone please shed light on how can I redirect the page correctly?

Comment: For note, `componentWillMount` is deprecated

Comment: Can you show the complete code of the `Search` component ?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami Done! All the necessary code is already in the question now. I changed the class name from `Search` to `SearchForItem` since I am already rendering <Search />.

Answer (score 0):

Currently working on this right now as well, the only way I have come up with doing it (not without its flaws) is using this.props.history.push("{LINK TO REDIRECT HERE}") in the handleResultSelect arrow function. Will probably come back and update this answer after I have hashed out the issues but I believe this is the best way to do it.